# Should you save an argument to an instance variable when it's going to be passed through multiple methods?

Tags: java, oop

If you're going to be passing an argument through several methods of an object, is it wise to save that argument to an instance variable?

For example:

```
public class Example {
    private int[] array;

    public void doThingsToArray(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
        // `array` doesn't need to be passed as an argument.
        doFirstThingToArray();
        doSecondThingToArray();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

In this case, the same instance of `Example` will be used to call `doThingsToArray()` on multiple arrays, so you can't just pass `array` as an argument to `Example`'s constructor.

The pro I can see is that you don't have to pass `array` as an argument, and - according to Clean Code, at least - the fewer parameters a method has, the better.

I can't come up with a solid con, but I sense something wrong with this situation.

Comment: Solid con: that immediately makes you class non thread-safe. The field is not part of the state of the object as it should be, but is just a temporary value used by some methods.

Comment: I think the first question that needs to be answered is "why is a method called `doThingsToArray()` doing something other than modifying the array?"

Comment: What if you don't intend to use multiple threads? I suppose there's always the chance that you'll want to do so at a later point.

Comment: "... according to Clean Code, at least - the fewer parameters a method has, the better." This does not mean that "no parameters" is "great". It just means: If you get too many parameters, pack them in some `ConfigurationObject` and let the method have a parameter of `ConfigurationObject`.

Comment: Another con is that it's not immediately clear which methods need to be called in which order. IIRC Clean Code discusses this scenario and suggests using arguments and return values to clearly outline the invocation chain.

Comment: Or delegate to some ArrayComputer object whose state really is the array.

Comment: Another reason to eschew instance variables in favor of parameters is ease of testing.  If each sub-method takes and returns an array, they can all be independently tested.

Comment: Part of the inspiration for this question was seeing a similar style used in Clean Code. It gave me a vague feeling of unease. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Now instead you can have a clearly defined feeling of unease! =)

Comment: @Pig I suspect you were looking at classes whose entire purpose was to execute a particular computation (i.e. command pattern). In such a case it might be cleaner to keep a variable or two on the class instead of having to pass them to each individual step. But if it's more of a data object, especially if it's shared, it can be dangerous and confusing to have a state change broken down over multiple methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you're going to be passing an argument through several methods of an object, is it wise to save that argument to an instance variable?

No, it is not wise to do that.

From a design perspective, the value you propose to stash in an instance variable is not a property of the object; rather, it is a property of a given computation.  As such, method arguments and / or local variables are where it belongs, and it absolutely does not belong in an instance variable.

From a practical perspective, relying on the value being stashed in an instance variable breaks thread safety.  You cannot have multiple computations running simultaneously on the same object, because each one expects to be able to use the same instance variable for its own purposes.

Comment: So instance variables should only describe the state of the object?

Comment: @Pig, yes.  That is practically a definition of "object oriented".

Comment: It also obscures the logic, making the code very fragile. E.g. when does the field have a valid value? If you, in some future modification, try to use the field before it has been assigned, you get a `null` value. If you try to use it outside the method invocation, you may see a stale value from the last call, whatever call that may be. So even in a single-threaded app, it's extremely problematic.